# How to delete a folder that may be a junction, and the destination using command line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, symbolic-link, junction

I want to completely remove a 'folder' that may or may not be a junction to another folder.
If the 'folder' isn't a junction `rd /s /q 'folder'` will do the job.

But if the 'folder' is a junction to another folder I found that:

In Windows XP, `rd /s /q` will delete the junction and everything inside the destination folder but doesn't remove the destination folder.

In Windows 7, `rd /s /q` will only delete the junction, and the destination folder isn't touched.

My question is, given a 'folder' that may or may not be a junction to another folder, how can I completely remove it using the command line?

Comment: I have been thinking about this for some time, and I can't think of an alternative to parsing the `dir` listing and removing the target and the link separately, according to what the entry shows. Maybe PowerShell can do a better job, but I have only the most cursory knowledge of it.

Comment: Will using "del /f/s/q foldername > nul" then "rmdir /s/q foldername" work for you? The first command ensures there are no files and the second deletes the folder & subfolders.